# Telerik Kendo grid for jquery does not show data

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

My kendo grid is define as followed:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
batch: false,
autoSync: true,
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules?format=json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 30000
    },
    update: {
        url: "/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules/updateroutecontentrule",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "PUT"
    },
    create: {
        url: "/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules/createroutecontentrule",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"
    },
    destroy: {
        url: "/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules/deleteroutecontentrule",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "DELETE"
    },
    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
        if (operation == "read") {
            return kendo.stringify({
                RouteId: routeDataItem.RouteId
            });
        }
        else if (operation == "destroy") {
            return kendo.stringify({
                Id: data.Id,
            });
        }
        else {
            return kendo.stringify({
                Id: data.Id,
                RouteId: routeDataItem.RouteId,
                OrderId: data.OrderId,
                SenderMatch: data.SenderMatch,
                ContentMatch: data.ContentMatch,
                SenderReplace: data.SenderReplace,
                ContentReplace: data.ContentReplace,
            });
        }
    }
},
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            Id: { type: "number", defaultValue: 0 },
            OrderId: { type: "number", defaultValue: 0 },
            SenderMatch: { type: "string", defaultValue: "" },
            ContentMatch: { type: "string", defaultValue: "" },
            SenderReplace: { type: "string", defaultValue: "" },
            ContentReplace: { type: "string", defaultValue: "" }
        }
    }
}});$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: dataSource,
reorderable: false,
resizable: false,
sortable: false,
groupable: false,
scrollable: true,
navigatable: true,
editable: true,
columns: [
    {
        width: 150, field: "SenderMatch", title: "Sender match",
        template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
        headerAttributes: { title: "Sender match", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
    },
    {
        width: 150, field: "ContentMatch", title: "Content match",
        template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
        headerAttributes: { title: "Content match", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
    },
    {
        width: 150, field: "SenderReplace", title: "Sender replace",
        template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
        headerAttributes: { title: "Sender replace", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
    },
    {
        width: 150, field: "ContentReplace", title: "Content replace",
        template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
        headerAttributes: { title: "Content replace", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
    },
    {
        command: [
            { name: "destroy", template: "<a class='k-button k-grid-delete delete'><span class='k-sprite px-sprite px-i-sm-trash'></span></a>" }
        ],
        width: "50px"
    }
],
toolbar: kendo.template('<span class="ReloadManipulationByCustomer" style=""><span class="k-icon k-i-refresh refresh-btn"></span></span><a class="k-button k-grid-add add-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="k-sprite px-sprite px-i-sm-new new" />Add</a>')});$(".ReloadManipulationByCustomer").click(function () {
$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();});
```

For backend I am using ServiceStack, requests are define as followed:

```
    [Route("/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules/createroutecontentrule", "POST")]
[Route("/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules/updateroutecontentrule", "PUT")]
public sealed class CreateUpdateRouteContentRuleRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
 
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
 
    public string SenderMatch { get; set; }
 
    public string ContentMatch { get; set; }
 
    public string SenderReplace { get; set; }
 
    public string ContentReplace { get; set; }
}
 
[Route("/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules")]
public sealed class RouteContentRulesRequest
{
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
}
 
[Route("/monitoring/matrix/routecontentrules/deleteroutecontentrule")]
public sealed class DeleteRouteContentRuleRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
 
public sealed class RouteContentRuleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
 
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
 
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
 
    public string SenderMatch { get; set; }
 
    public string ContentMatch { get; set; }
 
    public string SenderReplace { get; set; }
 
    public string ContentReplace { get; set; }
}
```

Code for retrieving data is as follows:

```
    public object Post(RouteContentRulesRequest request)
{
    return _dbConnectionFactory
        .OpenReadOnlyAndRun(dbConn => dbConn.Select<RouteContentRule>(r => r.RouteId == request.RouteId).OrderBy(r => r.OrderId));
}

public object Any(CreateUpdateRouteContentRuleRequest request)
{
    RouteContentRule entity;

    if (!Db.Exists<Route>(new { Id = request.RouteId }))
    {
        throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, $"Route with id {request.RouteId} does not exist");
    }
    if (request.Id != 0)
    {
        var routeContentRule = _dbConnectionFactory.OpenReadOnlyAndRun(dbConn => dbConn.SingleById<RouteContentRule>(request.Id));
        entity = request.ToEntity(routeContentRule);
        Db.Update(entity, r => r.Id == routeContentRule.Id);
        return entity.ToModel();
    }

    entity = request.ToEntity();
    entity.OrderId = (_dbConnectionFactory.OpenReadOnlyAndRun(dbConn => dbConn.Scalar<RouteContentRule, int?>(x => Sql.Max(x.OrderId), x => x.RouteId == request.RouteId)) ?? 0) + 1;
    var id = (int)Db.Insert(entity, true);
    entity.Id = id;

    return entity.ToModel();
}

public void Delete(DeleteRouteContentRuleRequest request)
{
    Db.Delete<RouteContentRule>(new {Id = request.Id});
}
```

Data during read request is as follows:

```
    [
   {
      "Id":35,
      "OrderId":1,
      "RouteId":72303,
      "SenderMatch":"335",
      "ContentMatch":"",
      "SenderReplace":"",
      "ContentReplace":""
   },
   {
      "Id":36,
      "OrderId":2,
      "RouteId":72303,
      "SenderMatch":"55",
      "ContentMatch":"",
      "SenderReplace":"",
      "ContentReplace":""
   }
]
```

Here are images from Chrome developers tools:
[image: server request]
[image: preview]
[image: response]

Problem is that grid is not showing these data. I can see that data is here if I click on grid cell. In that situation that cell become editable and it is showing current value of data. But as soon as I move editing to some new cell previous hide data. I was inspecting cell and I have found out that when cell is not editing it is described as following:

```
    <td style="text-align: right" aria-describedby="50349c08-da61-49d2-aa73-9c0823d4a4a4" role="gridcell">
    <span><label class="SenderMatch" <="" label=""></label></span>
</td>
```

And when cell is in edding mode it is described in html as following:

```
<td style="text-align: right" aria-describedby="ccc2df23-b49a-4b00-820a-02a67c428a52" role="gridcell" id="Grid_active_cell" class="k-edit-cell" data-role="editable">
    <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="SenderMatch" data-bind="value:SenderMatch">
</td>
```

I do not know why data is not showing. From what I can tell it should show data, but it is not showing this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what was the problem.

```
columns: [
{
    width: 150, field: "SenderMatch", title: "Sender match",
    template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
    headerAttributes: { title: "Sender match", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
},
{
    width: 150, field: "ContentMatch", title: "Content match",
    template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
    headerAttributes: { title: "Content match", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
},
{
    width: 150, field: "SenderReplace", title: "Sender replace",
    template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
    headerAttributes: { title: "Sender replace", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
},
{
    width: 150, field: "ContentReplace", title: "Content replace",
    template: "<span><label class='SenderMatch'</label></span>",
    headerAttributes: { title: "Content replace", style: "text-align: right" }, attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }
},
{
    command: [
        { name: "destroy", template: "<a class='k-button k-grid-delete delete'><span class='k-sprite px-sprite px-i-sm-trash'></span></a>" }
    ],
    width: "50px"
}],
```

Templates are buggy. I removed them and now data is shown. Template for command is still valid.

Comment: You're missing a greater greater than character in your label in template: `...class='SenderMatch'><...`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put `[Route]` attributes on your class....? They should be on `Controller`'s `Action`.

Then you can open Chrome's development tool and look at `network` tab to check whether the data is sending to the back-end.

You can paste the picture of `network` to show us when you think you should get the data, then we can check what problem is.

Comment: I uploaded images from chrome development tool.

About Route attribute. This is convention for Service Stack. As I said in my question I am using Service Stack on my backend, and not classic MVC.